# how to restrict users to only edit their records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Hey I hope you can help me.

I am using rails 3 with the devise gem.
I am trying to find a way to let users only edit the posts/comments that they have created.
Should I add the CanCan gem for this or can I do it with devise? Or is there just a simple Active Record query possible?

Many thanks.

Comment: IMO cancancan is the way to go from a long term perspective. you have more power and control that way, but at the cost of a small learning curve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Devise creates a hash `current_user`, which you can use in your controllers, models, and views. So it should be easy to create a check which does something like this:

```
@comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
if current_user.id == @comment.user.id
  # yadda
end
```

Comment: Or `current_user.comments.include?(@comment)`

Comment: I think using this method would still allow a malicious user to edit posts/comments belonging to others by editing the url. (i.e. .../comments/1/edit) Am I missing how this prevents users from making edits the way I just described?

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you have a relationship between `User` and `Post`/`Comment`, you can use this relationship to only fetch the records belonging to the user in your `edit` action:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    # Instead of this:
    # Post.find(params[:id])
    # Use this:
    current_user.posts.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

This will only find the post if the current user has created it.

Naturally, you'll have to modify the `update` action as well.

Comment: Bonus is that it will be automatically show 404 response if the post isn't found. Hmm.. but that isn't technically the right one. "Not authorized" or similar might be better.

Answer (score 1):

CanCan is a bit overkill for your needs but it would be more flexible for later evolutions.

Otherwise, just compare user_id and author_id.